# Magento 1.9 Enable Disable Module From Admin Panel

Tags: php, magento

I have a task to create a Magento module that's override some phtml files, however, as the task requirement I need to control the module from 
`system->configuration,` by creating a tab for the module, then an option for `enable disable the module`.

How could I accomplish this, taken into consideration the module contains the phtml file to override.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I prefer to create block which will render those templates, then, you can use override `_toHtml` method and implement the logic there. Similar to what the `Mage_Core_Block_Template` does.

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Template extends Mage_Core_Block_Template 
{
    ...

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (!this->_isEnabled()) {
            return '';
        } 

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    ...
}
```